# python convert quarterly time series to monthly

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series

Working with Python 3

I have a data frame with quarterly observation. 
I would like to duplicate the quarterly row into 3 monthly rows, keeping all other values equal (except the time variable).

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and your desired output with what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I have something similar to this

```
quarters = {'Quarters': [Q1/2016,Q2/2016,Q3/2016], 'Obs 1':[a,b,c], 'Obs 2':[I,II,III]}
quarters
```

And I would like to transform it into

```
months = {'Months': [01/2016,02/2016,03/2016,04/2016,05/2016,06/2016,07/2016,08/2016,09/2016], 'Obs 1':[a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,], 'Obs 2':[I,I,I,II,II,II,III,III,III]}
months
```